# Iterate/Loop through Datagrid rows to get the value of checkbox column using c# wpf

Tags: wpf, datagrid

i want to get the value of `CheckBoxColumn` in `DataGrid` wpf

i try this code

```
foreach (spShowTotal_Result item in dgShowStudent.ItemsSource)
            {
                if (item.boolCol == true)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("fail");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("success");

                }
            }
```

but don't take the changed value but take the same value of the my `ItemsSource` .

i try this code

```
foreach (spShowTotal_Result item in dgShowStudent.ItemsSource) { bool? check = ((CheckBox)dgShowStudent.Columns[0].GetCellContent(item)).IsChecked; }
```

but this error is appear Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox'.

Comment: tWhat is item ? What is boolCol ? Show some relevant code .

Comment: item in for each scope and boolCod is the column in db or itemsoursce

Comment: i try this code 
foreach (spShowTotal_Result item in dgShowStudent.ItemsSource)
            {

                bool? check = ((CheckBox)dgShowStudent.Columns[0].GetCellContent(item)).IsChecked;
            }
but this error is appear 
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox'.

Comment: Browse some questions to see how to user ask questions to get proper answers.

Comment: ok, i will edit the question now

Comment: Your CheckBox column would contain many values for separate rows. Which row are you interested in ?

Comment: all rows can change the value of te checkboxcolumn checked or not